# MySQL on Ubuntu Server & Windows Server 2012

Tags: php, mysql, windows

I'm after some advice...

Currently we have an Ubuntu Server through Vultr.com running a MySQL database, this is connected to a php site sitting on a Windows Server 2012 VM, this all works great no issues. We want to get away from having 2 servers and put the MySQL db on to the Windows Server VM, the MySQL is set up in exactly the same way as on the Ubuntu, db is a backup copy of the live, created replica php site for testing. All remote connections are established, tested using MySQL Workbench. Everything is the same, but for some reason I can't work out why the site connected to the local MySQL db on the Windows Server VM doesn't run through the code. I've put a copy of section of the query.log files for both machines, and the Windows log Quits running the code, but doesn't error. I've used the same code, Is there something in Windows Server that MySQL may not like or something I have maybe missed off on Installation.

I have used the site previously on a Windows Server VM but that had Plesk running and that was problem free also.

Vultr.Log - Ubuntu

```
160720  21:36:30    34489 Connect   mysqluser@mail.MyDomain on MyDB
        34489 Query CALL sp_pages('login.php')
        34489 Query SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = 'me@me.com'
        34489 Query INSERT INTO userhist (`UserID`, `DateOfAction`, `ActionType`) VALUES ('1', '2016-07-20 21:34:12', 'LogIn')
        34489 Quit  
        34490 Connect   mysqluser@mail.MyDomain on 
        34490 Init DB   MyDB
        34491 Connect   mysqluser@mail.spagetti.uk on sirps
        34491 Query SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '1'
        34491 Query SELECT * FROM usergroups WHERE id = '3'
        34491 Query INSERT INTO usershist (`UserID`, `DateOfAction`, `ActionType`) VALUES ('1', '2016-07-20 21:34:13', 'index.php')
        34491 Query CALL sp_pages('index.php')
        34491 Quit
```

Windows Server Log

```
2016-07-20T21:33:57.151901Z 2023 Connect    mysqluser@localhost on MyDB using TCP/IP
2016-07-20T21:33:57.151901Z 2023 Query  CALL sp_pages('login.php')
2016-07-20T21:33:57.151901Z 2023 Query  SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = 'me@me.com'
2016-07-20T21:33:57.151901Z 2023 Quit
```

I thought there maybe a connection issue, but tested and tested that and it connects, looked at the firewall and 3306 is established as a port on the server.

Has anyone an idea as to where I could look next? 
I've been searching and trying so many different things through the day to no avail

init.php

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 error_reporting (E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 'true');
 date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

 ini_set('session.save_path', 'J:\PHPSessions');

 $GLOBALS['config'] = array(
  'mysql' => array(
         'host'   => 'localhost',
   'username'  => 'MyUser',
   'password'  => 'MyPwd',
   'db'  => 'MyDB'
  ),
  'remember' => array(
   'cookie_name' => 'hash',
   'cookie_expiry' =>  604800
  ),
  'session' => array(
   'session_name' => 'user',
   'token_name' => 'token'
  )
 );

 // Autoload classes
 function autoload($class) {
  require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
 }
 spl_autoload_register('autoload');

 // Include functions
 require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';

 // Check for users that have requested to be remembered
 if(Cookie::exists(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'))) {
  $hash = Cookie::get(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'));
  $hashCheck = DB::getInstance()->get('userssession', array('hash', '=', $hash));

  if($hashCheck->count()) {
   $user = new User($hashCheck->first()->userid);
   $user->login();
  }
 }
```

db.php

```html
<?php
class DB {
 public static $instance = null;

 private  $_pdo = null,
    $_query = null,
    $_error = false,
    $_results = null,
    $_count = 0;

 private function __construct() {
  try {
   $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
  } catch(PDOExeption $e) {
   die($e->getMessage());
  }
 }

 public static function getInstance() {
  // Already an instance of this? Return, if not, create.
  if(!isset(self::$instance)) {
   self::$instance = new DB();
  }
  return self::$instance;
 }

 public function query($sql, $params = array()) {

  $this->_error = false;

  if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
   $x = 1;
   if(count($params)) {
    foreach($params as $param) {
     $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
     $x++;
    }
   }

   if($this->_query->execute()) {
    $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
   } else {
    $this->_error = true;
   }
  }
  
  return $this;
 }

 public function get($table, $where) {
  return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
 }

 public function delete($table, $where) {
  return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
 }

 public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
  if(count($where) === 3) {
   $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

   $field   = $where[0];
   $operator  = $where[1];
   $value   = $where[2];

   if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
    $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

    if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
     return $this;
    }

   }
   
   return false;
  }
 }

 public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
  $keys  = array_keys($fields);
  $values = null;
  $x   = 1;

  foreach($fields as $value) {
   $values .= "?";
   if($x < count($fields)) {
    $values .= ', ';
   }
   $x++;
  }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

  if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
   return true;
  }

  return false;
 }

 public function update($table, $id, $fields = array()) {
  $set  = null;
  $x  = 1;

  foreach($fields as $name => $value) {
   $set .= "{$name} = ?";
   if($x < count($fields)) {
    $set .= ', ';
   }
   $x++;
  }

  $sql = "UPDATE users SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

  if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
   return true;
  }

  return false;
 }

 public function results() {
  // Return result object
  return $this->_results;
 }

 public function first() {
  return $this->_results[0];
 }

 public function count() {
  // Return count
  return $this->_count;
 }

 public function error() {
  return $this->_error;
 }
}
```

user.php

```html
<?php
class User {
 private $_db,
   $_sessionName = null,
   $_cookieName = null,
   $_data = array(),
   $_isLoggedIn = false;

 public function __construct($user = null) {
  $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
  
  $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
  $this->_cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');

  // Check if a session exists and set user if so.
  if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName) && !$user) {
   $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

   if($this->find($user)) {
    $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
   } else {
    $this->logout();
   }
  } else {
   $this->find($user);
  }
 }

 public function exists() {
  return (!empty($this->_data)) ? true : false;
 }

 public function find($user = null) {
  // Check if user_id specified and grab details
  if($user) {
   $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
   $data = $this->_db->get('user', array($field, '=', $user));

   if($data->count()) {
    $this->_data = $data->first();
    return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
 }

 public function create($fields = array()) {
  if(!$this->_db->insert('user', $fields)) {
   throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account.');
  }
 }

 public function update($fields = array(), $id = null) {
  if(!$id && $this->isLoggedIn()) {
   $id = $this->data()->id;
  }
  
  if(!$this->_db->update('user', $id, $fields)) {
   throw new Exception('There was a problem updating.');
  }
 }

 public function login($username = null, $password = null, $remember = false) {

  if(!$username && !$password && $this->exists()) {
   Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
  } else {
   $user = $this->find($username);

   if($user) {
    if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
     Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);

     if($remember) {
      $hash = Hash::unique();
      $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

      if(!$hashCheck->count()) {
       $this->_db->insert('users_session', array(
        'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
        'hash' => $hash
       ));
      } else {
       $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
      }

      Cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash, Config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));
     }

     return true;
    }
   }
  }

  return false;
 }

 public function hasPermission($key) {
  $group = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id = ?", array($this->data()->group));
  
  if($group->count()) {
   $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

   if($permissions[$key] === 1) {
    return true;
   }
  }

  return false;
 }

 public function isLoggedIn() {
  return $this->_isLoggedIn;
 }

 public function data() {
  return $this->_data;
 }

 public function logout() {
  $this->_db->delete('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

  Cookie::delete($this->_cookieName);
  Session::delete($this->_sessionName);
 }
}
```

simple index.php version of my code

```html
<?php
require 'core/init.php';

$user = new User();

if(Session::exists('home')) {
 echo '<p>', Session::flash('home'), '</p>';
}

if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
 ?>
 
 <p>Hello <a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?>"><?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?></a>!</p>
 
 <ul>
  <li><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>
  <li><a href="changepassword.php">Change password</a></li>
  <li><a href="update.php">Update details</a></li>
 </ul>

 <?php

 if($user->hasPermission('admin')) {
 ?>
  <p>You're also an administrator!</p>
 <?php
 }

} else {
 echo 'You need to <a href="login.php">log in</a> or <a href="register.php">register</a>!';
}
```

Simple version of login.php

```html
<?php
require 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()) {
 if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
  $user = new User();

  $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
  $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);

  if($login) {
   Redirect::to('index.php');
  } else {
   echo '<p>Sorry, that username and password wasn\'t recognised.</p>';
  }
 }
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
 <div class="field">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <label for="remember">
   <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"> Remember me
  </label>
 </div>

 <input type="submit" value="Log in">
 <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
</form>
```

hash.php

```html
<?php
class Hash {
 public static function make($string, $salt = '') {
  return utf8_encode(hash('sha256', $string . $salt));
 }

 public static function salt($length) {
  return mcrypt_create_iv($length);
 }

 public static function unique() {
  return self::make(uniqid());
 }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: perhaps you ought to post some code

Comment: @e4c5 I thought to do so but so much of was unsure, but then why would code be an issue if has and is working on the Ubuntu db & Plesk platform on Windows VM previously?

Comment: can't say without looking! Why not post the code that executes the above statements? Have you tried adding debug statements?

Comment: I've posted some code above, have tried setting 'ini_set('display_errors', 'true');' but shows no error

Comment: What does your database log say?

Comment: I've posted the MySQL logs above, how do you get database logs in MySQL?

Comment: When connected to the Ubuntu server and echo out this statement both sections match `$this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)` , but when connected through the Windows Server, the `Hash::make` section creates a whole new string for some reason. Is there a reason for this with PHP, MySQL & Windows?